# Recursive backpropagation vs backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, recurrent-neural-network

I recently read a paper that tried to find out what happened in a RNN by linearization around slow and fixed points. I can't figure out why we have to use linearization around these points. After I read another paper about FIXED POINT ANALYSIS FOR RECURRENT NETWORKS, I found out that recursive backpropagation should converge to a stable fixed point in order to backpropagate the error signals. My questions are:

1. What's the main difference between recursive backpropagation and standard backpropagation?
2. Why must RBG converge to a fixed point?